# Use of generic points to show that $k$-tori are split over $k_s$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, fields

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$, and let $T$ be a $k$-torus.  To say that $k$-split is to say that every character $T \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m$ is defined over $k$.

The following result is standard.  It comes down to showing that if $T$ is split over a purely inseparable extension of $k$, then it is already split over $k$.  I have seen a proof in Springer, *Linear Algebraic Groups* which uses some facts about derivations.  But I wanted to understand this proof from Borel Tits, *Groupes Reductifs*:

[image]

I guess what they are doing in this proof is identifying $T$ with the group of invertible $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrices with coefficients in a universal field $\Omega$ containing $k$.  Then if $t = (t_1, ... , t_n)$ is a point of $T$, I think they mean $k(t)$ to be the field $k(t_1, ... , t_n)$.

To say that $t$ is **generic** is to say that $t_1, ...  ,t_n$ are algebraically independent over $k$.  In the proof, they show that if $t$ is generic over $k$, then the given character $a$ maps $t^q = (t_1^q, .. , t_n^q)$ into $k(t^q)$.  They seem to then conclude that $a(t^q) \subseteq k(t^q)$ for *all* points $t \in T$, which implies that the coefficients defining the morphism of varieties $a$ must lie in $k$, i.e. $a$ is defined over $k$.  I don't understand how what is written in the proof shows anything: what if $t$ is not generic over $k$?

Comment: I think the point is that this condition is "closed under specialization", so if it holds for "generic points" then it holds for all points. Just imagine that t is a transcendental over k, for instance, which you can specialize to be anything.

Comment: No need for derivations or generic points: use that $k' \otimes_k k'$ is local with residue field $k'$ (via diagonal) for purely inseparable finite extensions $k'/k$ and that the endomorphism group of $\mathbf{G}_m^r$ over *any* local ring is ${\rm{Mat}}_r(\mathbf{Z})$ (so any such is determined by its effect on the special fiber): see Exercise 1 in Homework 1 and Exercise 2 in Homework 2 at https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110662  One can always avoid the Weil perspective on generic points to prove things about algebraic groups (you may prefer otherwise).

Comment: @D_S: Your reference to Borel-Tits is confusing here, since you probably mean Bruhat-Tits.     Please identify the source.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: D_S meant to write Borel-Tits *Groupes Reductifs* (Publ. Math. IHES 27).

Comment: @nfdc23:  Thanks for the clarification.   It's probably useful here to add a link to the original article, though by now the mathematical language is not optimal as you've pointed out: http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__27__55_0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By $k(t)$, Borel-Tits mean the field of rational functions on $T$. It is, in general, not purely transcendental. The field $k(t^q)$ is the subfield of pull-backs of rational functions via the power map $\phi:T\to T:t\mapsto t^q$. Now they claim that $\overline k(t^q)\cap k(t)=k(t^q)$. Since $a^q(t)$ is an element of the left side it is of the form $b(t^q)$ with $b(t)\in k(t)$. But then the equality $a^q(t)=b(t^q)$ implies $a(t)=b(t)$. Thus $a(t)\in k(t)$. But a rational function which is a character is regular, i.e., $a(t)\in k[t]$.

By the way, the intersection $\overline k(t^q)\cap k(t)=k(t^q)$ works more generally: Let $\phi:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism between two geometrically integral $k$-varieties (e.g., they is smooth with a $k$-rational point). Then $\overline k(Y)\cap k(X)=k(Y)$ inside $\overline k(X)$ . To see this, first use $(\overline k\otimes_kk(Y))\cap k(X)=k(Y)$ inside $\overline k\otimes_kk(X)$ and then $\overline k\otimes_kk(X)=\overline k(X)$ and $\overline k\otimes_kk(Y)=\overline k(Y)$ by geometric integrality.